# Estimate product of Hölder functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the unit ball, let $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, and let $0 < \alpha < 1$. Let $f, g \in C^{k, \alpha}(U)$ be Hölder functions, i.e. $f$ and $g$ are of class $C^k$,
$$
|f|_{k, \alpha} = \sum_{|I| \le k} \sup_{x \in U} |D^If(x)| + \sum_{|I| = k} \sup_{x \neq y \in U}\frac{|D^If(x) - D^If(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha} < \infty
$$
and $|g|_{k, \alpha} < \infty$.

**Question.** *Is there a way to estimate $|fg|_{k,\alpha}$ in terms of some Hölder norms of $f$ and $g$? For instance, is it true that there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$
|fg|_{k, \alpha} \le C(|f|_{k, \alpha} |g|_k + |f|_k |g|_{k, \alpha})
$$
or something of that sort?*

I read in a book that the above inequality is true when $k = 0$ and I'm wondering what is the right generalization.

Comment: My first guess would be yes: Use the product rule and the fact that $[FG]_\alpha \lesssim [F]_\alpha\| G\|_\infty + \| F\|_\infty [G]_\alpha$ (where $[\cdot]_\alpha$ denotes the last quantity in your norm).

Answer (score 0):

I will change the notation and use
\begin{align*}
|h|_{0,\alpha}  & :=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|h(x)-h(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}},\\
\Vert h\Vert_{0,\alpha}  & :=\sup_{x}|h(x)|+|h|_{0,\alpha}.
\end{align*}
If $f,g\in C^{k,\alpha}(U)$, then for every multi-index $\beta$ the Leibnitz
formula
$$
\partial^{\beta}(fg)=\sum_{\gamma\leq\beta}c_{\gamma\beta}\partial
^{\beta-\gamma}f\partial^{\gamma}g
$$
holds for some $c_{\gamma\beta}\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
|\partial^{\beta-\gamma} &  f(x)\partial^{\gamma}g(x)-\partial^{\beta-\gamma
}f(y)\partial^{\gamma}g(y)|\leq|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f(x)\partial^{\gamma
}g(x)-\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f(x)\partial^{\gamma}g(y)|\\
&  \quad+|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f(x)\partial^{\gamma}g(y)-\partial
^{\beta-\gamma}f(y)\partial^{\gamma}g(y)|\\
&  \leq\sup_{U}|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f||\partial^{\gamma}g(x)-\partial
^{\gamma}g(y)|+\sup_{U}|\partial^{\gamma}g||\partial^{\beta-\gamma
}f(x)-\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f(y)|\\
&  \leq\sup_{U}|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f||x-y|^{\alpha}|\partial^{\gamma
}g|_{0,\alpha}+\sup_{U}|\partial^{\gamma}g||x-y|^{\alpha}|\partial
^{\beta-\gamma}f|_{0,\alpha},
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f\partial^{\gamma}g|_{0,\alpha}  & =\sup_{x\neq
y}\frac{|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f(x)\partial^{\gamma}g(x)-\partial
^{\beta-\gamma}f(y)\partial^{\gamma}g(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\\
& \leq\sup_{U}|\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f||\partial^{\gamma}g|_{0,\alpha}
+\sup_{U}|\partial^{\gamma}g||\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f|_{0,\alpha}.
\end{align*}
In turn,
\begin{align*}
|\partial^{\beta}(fg)|_{0,\alpha}  & \leq\sum_{\gamma\leq\beta}|c_{\gamma
\beta}||\partial^{\beta-\gamma}f\partial^{\gamma}g|_{0,\alpha}\\
& \leq\sum_{\gamma\leq\beta}|c_{\gamma\beta}|\sup_{U}|\partial^{\beta-\gamma
}f||\partial^{\gamma}g|_{0,\alpha}+\sup_{U}|\partial^{\gamma}g||\partial
^{\beta-\gamma}f|_{0,\alpha}.
\end{align*}
To conclude, it remains to show that if $h\in C^{k,\alpha}(U)$ and $\gamma$ is
multi-index, with length $|\gamma|=\ell<k$, then
$$
|\partial^{\gamma}h|_{0,\alpha}\leq C\Vert h\Vert_{0,\alpha}.
$$
By Taylor's formula
$$
\partial^{\gamma}h(x)=\partial^{\gamma}h(y)+\sum_{1\leq|\beta|<k-\ell}
\frac{(x-y)^{\beta}}{\beta!}\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h(y)+\sum_{|\beta|=k-\ell
}\frac{(x-y)^{\beta}}{\beta!}\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h(z),
$$
for some $z$ on the segment of endpoints $x$ and $y$. Hence,
$$
|\partial^{\gamma}h(x)-\partial^{\gamma}h(y)|\leq\sum_{1\leq|\beta|<k-\ell
}\frac{|x-y|^{|\beta|}}{\beta!}|\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h(0)|+\sum
_{|\beta|=k-\ell}\frac{|x-y|^{|\beta|}}{\beta!}|\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h(z)|,
$$
and so, since $\alpha\leq1$, $|x-y|\leq2$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{|\partial^{\gamma}h(x)-\partial^{\gamma}h(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}  &
\leq\sum_{1\leq|\beta|<k-\ell}\frac{|x-y|^{|\beta|-\alpha}}{\beta!}
|\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h(0)|+\sum_{|\beta|=k-\ell}\frac{|x-y|^{|\beta
|-\alpha}}{\beta!}|\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h(z)|\\
& \leq C\sum_{1\leq|\beta|\leq k-\ell}\sup_{U}|\partial^{\beta+\gamma}h|.
\end{align*}